# Unnecessary space in sentences

Tags: lists

[image]

There is unnecessary space coming in sentences,why this is happening .I have no idea about writting latex but Thanks to MathStack exchange because of downvotes i teach my self latex. But i have no idea how to solve his problem.please help me out

Thankyou.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `\linebreak` nor ``\\``. Use only a blank line instead (which you already have, so simply remove `\linebreak`).

Comment: Tankyou @PhelypeOleinik it works ,but lines are coming close should i use \vsapce comment?

Comment: No. As a rule of thumb, if you have to repeatedly use a command (like you were using `\linebreak`, or want to use `\vspace`), you're using it wrong. Try using an `enumerate` environment. See here for some examples: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists

Comment: Instead of posting code as a screenshot, please include it directly into your question.

Comment: ok @leandriis next time i will take care of this.